# How to change css attributes when column collapses in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

http://jsfiddle.net/rLz6s/

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2 text-right">Step 1.</div>
        <div class="clearfix visible-xs"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-10> Click to Upload Photos</div>
      </div>
```

The "Step" tabs have text aligned right when it's desktop width, but when it collapses, I'd like it to have text aligned left.

Is there a simple way to do this in Bootstrap 3?  Sorry, I'm still trying to get the hang of this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this can't be done with class attributes alone unfortunately.

Since the tabs all have the `.nb` class you can override `.text-align` for the xs breakpoint with a media query.

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .text-right.nb {
        text-align: left;
    }
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/rLz6s/3/

Comment: Perfect! exactly what I was looking for.  Now you just opened my eyes to doing other things using this media query.  thanks!